# Which Stack Exchange site for website-user questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Basically, questions like "I'm a user, I'm having trouble with website X, and I think it's them, not me."
I'm experiencing what seems like a bug in a text field in Amazon.com, and [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour) kicked out my question as being "off-topic".

Answer (score 5):

[Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)
is a question and answer site for [power] users of web applications. 
Their [What topics can I ask about
here?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page says:

> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google,
>   or any other website which behaves like an application
> - Features of browsers which are directly related to the use
>   of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!